# stripping the space from float value in key value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

Contex: In logstash I'm having a error like this:

```
{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"mapper [somekey] cannot be changed from type [long] to [float]"}
```

This is actually a bug BUT I cant move to a different logstash version and yes ive tried templates etc etc ...  I found the root of the problem in my case. When the dict is entered like this it fails:

```
{u'somekey': 0.03}
```

If I manually go in and modify the output dict to

```
{u'somekey':0.03}
```

It works perfectly.

My problem is I don't want to go through the output of dict to make the fix I'd like to fix it in code before it gets written to dict. But I cant seem to eliminate the space. Here is what I tried to do in python just to test:

```
somedict_dict[u'somekey'] = 0.03
print(somedict_dict)
>>>{u'somekey': 0.03}
```

Also tried:

```
somedict_dict[u'somekey'] =0.03
print(somedict_dict)
```

but ended up with the same result:

```
>>>{u'somekey': 0.03}
```

Any good way to do this?

Comment: `{u'somekey': 0.03}` is not JSON format.

Comment: I don't see any JSON here.

Comment: If you want to output valid JSON, don't use `str`, use `json.dumps`. That's why the `json` module exists. If it was built in there wouldn't be a need for another module.

Comment: sorry all I fixed the edit I meant dict, I was just working on json before and this popped in my head .

Comment: `>>>{u'somekey': 0.03}` The space after the colon makes absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be to convert your dictionary into a string and remove the spaces. This will cause issues if your keys or values are supposed to have spaces however it works for this example.

```
>>> somedict_dict = {}
>>> somedict_dict[u'somekey'] = 0.03
>>> output_str = str(somedict_dict).replace(": ", ":")
>>>
>>> print(output_str)
{'somekey':0.03}
```

Comment: You might want to say `.replace(": ", ":")` to avoid removing spaces in the keys or values.

Comment: @MikeChen Good point, such an obvious improvement. Edited, thanks!.